# What tools can I use to download videos from Youtube and Vimeo on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube

I am using 12.04 LTS. Can anyone suggest a simple software that can download videos from Youtube and Vimeo?

Answer (score 13):

### [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/documentation.html)

youtube-dl is a small command-line program to download videos from YouTube, Vimeo and a few more sites. It is included in the Ubuntu repositories, so you may install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

### [vimeo-dl](http://code.google.com/p/trizen/downloads/detail?name=vimeo-dl&can=2&q=)

vimeo-dl is a stand-alone command-line program to download videos from Vimeo. It is not included in the Ubuntu repositories, therefore you must download and save the script somewhere and make it executable by typing:

```
chmod 775 <script>
```

Comment: You should download it directly from the website instead from the repository because that's a outdated version. rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html Follow the 2 commands given there.

Comment: your [vimeo-dl](http://code.google.com/p/trizen/downloads/detail?name=vimeo-dl&can=2&q=) does not work. it only directs you to a bunch of unrelated stuff

Answer (score 8):

ClipGrab is a free software for downloading and converting online videos from many sites like YouTube or Vimeo.

ClipGrab can download from the following sites: YouTube, Clipfish, Collegehumor, Dailymotion, MyVideo, MySpass, Sevenload, Tudou, Vimeo.

To Install ClipGrab

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

<sup>Source: http://www.bestubuntu.com/how-to-install-clipgrab-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-using-ppa.html (may not be original source)</sup>

Comment: but it only works as GUI, not as command line

Answer (score 4):

I am using for some year a Firefox add-on: DownloadHelper. With it you can download video and music, you have control in codecs and formats in a immediate simple way

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[Mobile Media Convertor](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php) is the best and simplest I've found for Youtube. It converts Youtube videos as easy as dragging and dropping. It's available in the [Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mobilemediaconverter) and there's even an [online version](http://www.miksoft.net/momeco.php) of it. It will also convert many other formats but unfortunately, I don't think it works on Vimeo.

Answer (score 2):

For YouTube videos I totally recommend using [YouTube Video Download](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62634).

[image]

It should both work in Firefox, Chrome/ium and the major web browsers.

For Vimeo you can use any of the tools suggested here, such as `vimeo-dl` or `clibgrab`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend flashgot, if you use firefox. It's basicly one click download when you have set it up.

[image: FlashGot]

[Link to flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/?src=search)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of them, they all do the same thing, download video. The only things that will matter is how you use them, and you're the only one to know wich one the best for you so you should go onto the Ubuntu Software Center and type in the search: youtube. You'll see pretty much all of the opporunities. If you wanna go further, open up the terminal and type`apt-cache search youtube` You can also change "youtube" for another word such as video or downloader and when you think it's the one type `sudo apt-get install TheExactNameOfTheFile`

Answer (score 0):

Most convenient tool I discovered several years ago is [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.net/). Free, cross-platform and localized. It can work as regular d/l manager, and as "special downloader" for grabbing videos from many sources like YouTube, xhamster :-) and so on.

JVM is required and may be d/l-ed with installation kit or it can use existing one.